# how to properly capture `diff` output in buffer (without first opening a file)?

Tags: process, diff, diff-mode

## summary

If one captures `diff` output to a file name=`*.diff` and opens that file in a buffer, one gets nicely-formatted mode=`Diff`. How to get that directly, without first capturing to a file?

## details

I use `diff` a lot, not only via `ediff-buffers` (which I love) but also for more obscure purposes, like `diff`ing outputs of processes. I've also been using Emacs for several decades, but continue to learn new aspects and uses. So I was not so much surprised as curious to find that, when I did (from the dir/folder of a local `git` repo)

```
$ git diff master origin/master > /tmp/foo__local_vs_remote.diff
```

and opened the file in a buffer, it displayed in a nicely/usefully colorized (à la `ediff`) mode=Diff. I had just never before simultaneously

1. captured `diff` output to a file
2. named the file `*.diff`
3. opened the file in Emacs

But now I'm trying to capture `diff` output directly to a buffer *and* get output like that of the happy mode=Diff, and am failing.

### seeking genericity

Note also that, since I use `diff` in lots of contexts, I'm looking for a solution to the general problem, and not, e.g., just to the `git diff` problem (which I suspect Magit etc have solved). Seeking genericity, I'll test 3 usecases: "normal" file-vs-file `diff`, `git diff`, and process-substitution `diff`.

### platform

```
$ lsb_release -ds
LMDE 2 Betsy
$ cat /etc/debian_version
8.3
$ uname -rv
3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u4 (2016-02-29)
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 24.4.1
```

### options

#### shell-command

If I do the following (possibly after navigating to a buffer with an appropriate working directory)

1. `M-! <diff command/>`
2. `C-x b` `*Shell Command Output*` (where the output of `M-!`==`M-x shell-command` goes by default)
3. `M-x diff-mode`

... I get the nicely-formatted output. Furthermore

- this works for all 3 testcases
- if one runs `M-!` with another `diff` command, the new output just overwrites the old, but the buffer maintains `diff-mode` without user intervention
- no keybinding changes (as with term-mode)

Chosen answer.

#### shell-mode

If I either

1. `M-x shell`, goto the correct dir/folder, and run `git diff master origin/master`
2. am in a buffer on the correct dir/folder, and run `M-& git diff master origin/master`

I get the dreaded `WARNING: terminal is not fully functional`.

#### term-mode

As [Emacs User points out](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20736/5444), `M-x term` performs better for this usecase than `M-x shell`: if I `M-x term`, goto the correct dir/folder, and run `git diff master origin/master`, I get nicely colorized output. It's not exactly mode=Diff, but it does the job. Unfortunately

- That only works for `git diff`: I get no colorization for either process-substitution or file `diff`.
- I find the [term-mode keybinding changes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20736/5444) highly annoying.
- I also found term-mode navigation odd: when editing history, my cursor would sometimes bounce around oddly.
  solved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

1. `M-! <your diff command/>`
2. `C-x b` `*Shell Command Output*` (where the output of `M-!`==`M-x shell-command` goes by default)
3. `M-x diff-mode`

Comment: see reasons for choosing in question section=shell-command

Comment: Those reading this answer should be aware that the `WARNING: terminal is not fully functional` is not solved by this accepted solution. It may work for this limited diff case, but if one is `seeking genericity` as the OP requested, please use `M-x term` as a complete solution. See the Emacs documentation for reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You can always write a function to do all the repeated steps for you. This should get you started:

```
(defun diff-generic(command)
  (interactive "sDiff command:")
  (let ((buffer (generate-new-buffer "*diff-generic*")))
    (with-current-buffer buffer (diff-mode))
    (call-process-shell-command command nil buffer 0)
    (switch-to-buffer buffer)))
```

In general you can do `M-x diff` to get that diff output for two arbitrary files. More info on that here: `(info "(emacs) Diff Mode")`

Magit does provide diff functionality, but take note that it uses it's own mode called `magit-diff-mode`, that is different from generic emacs `diff-mode`.

Also emacs bundled package `VC` provides diff functionality for version control diffs. Unlike magit it works with backends other than git and uses `diff-mode`, also you can use `ediff`. Relevant manual: `(info "(emacs) Old Revisions")`

Comment: see section='seeking genericity'. How will this handle, e.g., process substitution?

Comment: I've updated my answer, this should what you want.